# MessageDialog in eclipse is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, dialog

I have the following code.

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(new Shell(), "title", null, "message", MessageDialog.QUESTION, choices, 0);  // choices is an array
```

It is giving NPE when I do `dialog.open()`. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some of  values might be null in `choices`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create a shell like that. You need to access an existing Shell from the context where you are launching the dialog. If you have a reference to any SWT control, you can access the shell from there.

Comment: Agreed, the first argument is suppose to be the parent shell.

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to use a MessageDialog is via one of the static open* methods, e.g. `MessageDialog.openInformation(...)`. But your issue might be related to the shell you pass.